# Not displaying results of a search

Tags: laravel, search

I have a Messaging module wherein a client, and a therapist can interact. Inside my inbox consists of the names of the clients. Now, I am the therapist, in my inbox shows the client that I have communicated. I want to search the name of the specific client by first name or last name perhaps. But it doesn't work the way I wanted it to. Is there something wrong with my code?

**Controller**

```php
public function findName(Therapist $therapists, Request $request)
{
    $query = Therapist::query();

    $therapist = $query->whereUserId(Auth::user())->with('user');

    $therapist->with([
        'contacts' => function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->when($request->name, function ($q) use ($request) {
                $q->whereHas('client', function ($q) use ($request) {
                    $q->whereRaw('CONCAT(fname, " ", lname) LIKE "%'.$request->name.'%"');
                });
            })
            ->with('client.user')
            ->latest();
        },
    ]);

    $therapist = $therapist->first();

    return view('therapist.message', compact('contacts'));
}
```

This is my view.

```php
<div class="headind_srch">
    {!! Form::open(['url' => url()->current(), 'method' => 'get']) !!}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {!! Form::inputGroup('text', null, 'name', request()->name ?? null, ['placeholder' => 'Client Name']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right"><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
<div class="inbox_chat">
    @foreach($contacts AS $contact)
        <div class="chat_list {{ $recipient == $contact->user_id ? 'active_chat' : '' }}">
            <div class="chat_people align-items-center d-flex"> <!--h-->
                <div class="incoming_msg_img">
                    <img src="">
                </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label onclick="javascript:window.location.href = '{{ route('therapist.index', $contact->user_id) }}'"
                               style="cursor:pointer;">
                            {{ $contact->fullname }}
                            &nbsp;
                            @if(optional($threadList->get($contact->user_id))->unseen_count)
                                <div class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary chat_date">
                                    {{ optional($threadList->get($contact->user_id))->unseen_count  }}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right_side_btn" id=""> <!--s-->
                    <div class="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <a data-id="{{$contact['id']}}" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-{{$contact['id']}}">
                                    <button type="submit"
                                            style="cursor:pointer; border: none; background-color: white;">
                                        Delete thread
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I expect it to display the name of the client by search either by first name or last name. The actual result is showing all the available users available.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the variable $contacts

```
$query = Therapist::query();

$therapist = $query->whereUserId(Auth::user())->with('user');

$therapist->with([
    'contacts' => function ($q) use ($request) {
        $q->when($request->name, function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereHas('client', function ($q) use ($request) {
                $q->whereRaw('CONCAT(fname, " ", lname) LIKE "%'.$request->name.'%"');
            });
        })
        ->with('client.user')
        ->latest();
    },
]);
$contacts = $therapist->first()->contacts;
return view('therapist.message', compact('contacts'));
```